# Reading lines with BufferedReader and checking for end of file

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, readline

If I have something like this in my code:

```
String line = r.readLine();  //Where r is a bufferedReader
```

How can I avoid a crash if the next line is the end of the file? (i.e. null)

I need to read the next line because there may be something there that I need to deal with but if there isn't the code just crashes.

If there is something there then all is OK, but I can't be guaranteed that there will be something there.

So if I do something like: (pseudo code):

```
if (r.readLine is null)
//End code

else {check line again and excecute code depending on what the next line is}
```

The issue I have with something like this is, that when I check the line against null, it already moves onto the next line, so how can I check it again?

I've not worked out a way to do this - any suggestions would be a great help.

Comment: Really wish people would leave a reason when down-voting. A down-vote is supposed to indicate there is something wrong with a question so maybe it can be reformatted. Down-voting without leaving a reason as to why the downvote has been cast helps no-one

Answer (score 48):

Am... You can simply use such a construction:

```
String line;

while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
   // do your stuff...
}
```

Comment: As you answered first, I'll delete mine:)

Answer (score 8):

If you want loop through all lines use that:

```
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
br.close();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following to check for the end of file.

```
public bool isEOF(BufferedReader br)  
{
     boolean result;

     try 
     {
         result = br.ready();
     } 
     catch (IOException e)
     {
         System.err.println(e);
     }
     return result;
}
```

Comment: This is better than assigning + comparing in the while clause, in my opinion.

Comment: This fails silently on exception and BufferedReader::ready can return false even if the next read will succeed.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can read the next line because there may be something there.If there isn't anything, your code won't crash.

```
String line = r.readLine();
while(line!=null){
   System.out.println(line);
   line = r.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Keeping the assignment out of the while clause keeps it much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

A question in the first place, why don't you use "**Functional Programming Approach**"? Anyways, A new method **lines()** has been added since **Java 1.8**, it lets **BufferedReader** returns content as **Stream**. It gets all the lines from the file as a stream, then you can sort the string based on your logic and then collect the same in a list/set and write to the output file. If you use the same approach, there is no need to get worried about **NullPointerException**. Below is the code snippet for the same:-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LineOperation {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("C://xyz.txt")).
            lines().
            collect(Collectors.toSet()). // You can also use list or any other Collection
            forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no reason to collect the lines.  Remove the `collect()` call and do `forEach()` on the stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via `BufferReader`. I know this is not relevant to following question. But I would post it for extra fact for a newbie who would not use `BufferReader` but `Scanner` for reading file.

A part from `BufferReader` you could use Java `Scanner` class to read the file and check the last line.

**Buffer Reader**

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       // process the line
    }
}
```

**Scanner**

```
   try {
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
         while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            // Above checks whether it has or not ....
            }
       } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

If you use this code fragment in a multi threaded environment, go ahead with `BufferReader` since its `synchronized`.

In addition, `BufferReader` is faster than `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do some check like:

```
if (reader.ready())
       stringBuilder.append("#");
```

You can use ready()

```
public static void check() throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            if (reader.ready())
                stringBuilder.append("#");
        }
        String returnedString = stringBuilder.toString();
        System.out.println(returnedString);
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

You could purposely have it throw the error inside your loop. i.e.:

```
String s = "";
while (true) {
    try {
        s = r.readline();
    }catch(NullPointerException e) {
        r.close();
        break;
    }
    //Do stuff with line
}
```

what everyone else has sad should also work.

Comment: Would this actually throw `NullPointerException`? I think you need to check `if (s == null)`.